# Autocomplete ordering

Tags: autocomplete

I'm using `12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)`, and the autocomplete feature is a bit of a mess. In previous versions I used to be able to type `Ta` and hit the `tab` key, and this was autocompleted into `Table`, an extremely useful tool. But now the ordering of the autocomplete suggestions is rather bad, for the first suggestion is `TableForm` instead of `Table`, and I see myself going back to fix things all the time. Is there any way to set up a preferred set of commands for the autocomplete feature? If this could be done automatically (say, order by frequency of usage) that'd be great, but even a manual choice of priority would be better than the current ordering.

Answer (score 3):

I've just tried your exact example on Win10-64 and MMA 12 and `Ta` + tab in fact autocompletes to `Table` in my system. You may try deleting your autocompletion history.

You can find that here:

```
FileNameJoin[{
  $UserBaseDirectory, 
  "SystemFiles\\FrontEnd\\SystemResources\\FunctionalFrequency\\AutocompletionHistory.m"}
]
```

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Yes, they should be! I fixed it; thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: An OS independent way to create the file name is to use: `FileNameJoin[{
  $UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "SystemResources", "FunctionalFrequency", "AutocompletionHistory.m"}
]`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunaltely, this didn't work. BTW, could you try with `Cl`? This used to autocomplete into `Clear`, but now it becomes `CloudDeploy`! (I've never used this function, not even sure what it does...)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform `Cl` autocompletes to `ClearAll` on my system; that makes sense to me, since I use `ClearAll` much more often than `Clear`. Indeed `ClearAll` appears in my AutocompletionHistory.m file associated with a higher value than `Clear`. I take that value to indicate priority.

Comment: @MarcoB any indication as to if you can deliberately mark one suggestion high than the others, in order to brute-force a solution to this?

Comment: @CATrevillian I haven’t been able to try that yet. It would seem a reasonable assumption though.